# How to add legend to a pie chart D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've looked through similar questions but still can't implement code correctly.

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var percentageFormat = d3.format("%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.json("staff.json", function(error, json_data) {

var data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
  return d.Position;
})
.rollup(function(d) {
  return d.length;
}).entries(json_data);

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.percentage = d.values / json_data.length;
});

console.log("data variable", data);
console.log("pie(data)", pie(data));

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "arc")
.on('mouseover', function() {
  var current = this;  
  var others = svg.selectAll(".arc").filter(function(el) {
    return this != current
  });
  others.selectAll("path").style('opacity', 0.8);
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
  var current = this;
  d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1);
  var others = svg.selectAll(".arc").filter(function(el) {
    return this != current
  });
  others.selectAll("path").style('opacity', 1);
});


g.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d, i) {
  return color(i);
});

g.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
})
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) {
  console.log("d is", d);
  return percentageFormat(d.data.percentage);
});
```

Here's a JSON-file:

```
[{
"Position" : "Programmer",
    "Name" : "Giacomo Gulizzoni",
     "Age" : 37,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Marko Botton",
     "Age" : 34,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Mariah Maclachian",
     "Age" : 37,
     "Sex" : "Female",
 "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
"Position" : "Tester",
    "Name" : "Valerie Liberty",
     "Age" : 25,
     "Sex" : "Female",
 "Project" : "SmartProject"
}, {
"Position" : "Programmer",
   "Name " : "Guido Jack Gulizzoni",
     "Age" : 22,
     "Sex" : "Male",
 "Project" : "SmartProject"
}]
```

Actually, legends are just rectangles that are bound to data if I'm not mistaken. But in my case items in JSON file are not numerical values. Have look at [my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/azr7vxkIMqkSTYPxbo6H?p=preview) for the results of my experiments.

Comment: Here's my plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/azr7vxkIMqkSTYPxbo6H?p=preview

Comment: Are you looking for tool tip or legend, If you are looking for legend what do you want to show, or If you are looking for tool tip what do you want to show in that.

Comment: Saikiran, I want something like this: one legend is for Programmers and another is for Testers. In other words, user should see what it means 60% and 40%.

Comment: You can modify 
`text(function(d) {
      console.log("d is", d);
      return percentageFormat(d.data.percentage);
    });`
into
`.text(function(d) {
      console.log("d is", d);
      return d.data.key+" - "+percentageFormat(d.data.percentage);
    });`
Try it.

Comment: It's not exactly what I want). I need this: https://gyazo.com/ef56dfd4b313ee95512af7e42ca13a32 But now I have this: http://joxi.ru/D2PYOeduM59YA3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

You are setting the data in the legend selection wrong

```
  var legend = ...
  .data(pie(data))//this is wrong
  .enter().append("g")
```

You need to do like this

```
      var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)//setting the data as we know there are only two set of data[programmar/tester] as per the nest function you have written
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
  return color(d.key);
});

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KxIGVU1YjWgxDNLSSxCh?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cyril, it's brilliant, thank you! I'm puzzled with this d3 a little) Going to study your decision! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was in your code,

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     // NEW
          .data(pie(data))                                   // NEW
          .enter()                                                // NEW
          .append('g')                                            // NEW
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                // NEW
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     // NEW
            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          // NEW
            var offset =  height * pie(data).length / 2;     // NEW
            var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;                       // NEW
            var vert = i * height - offset;                       // NEW
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        // NEW
          }); 
        legend.append('rect')                                     // NEW
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)                          // NEW
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)                         // NEW
          .style('fill', function(d,i){return color(i);})                                   // NEW
          .style('stroke', function(d,i){return color(i);});                                // NEW

        legend.append('text')                                     // NEW
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)              // NEW
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)              // NEW
          .text(function(d) { console.log("text: ");console.log(d);return d.data.key; });
```

I've un commented and did little changes.
You can observe the code.